# React Router - Remove Link components after clicked on?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, url-routing

When using React Router, how can I unmount/remove the div a Link component is in, or the Link component itself, when the Link is clicked on and the routing is complete?

For example, I have an app structured like this:

```
==Header==
==Link1 Link2==
```

When the user is routed to `Link1`, the `==Link1 Link2==` div should be unmounted/removed and replaced by the content of `Link1`. Like this:

```
==Header==
==Content of Link1, with a "back" button links to home page==
```

I am able to render the content of Link1 when user clicked on `Link1` in the navigation bar, and I've tried hard to restructure the `BrowserRouter`, `Route`, `div` tags, but the result remains like this:

```
==Header==
==Link1 Link2==
==Content of Link1, with a "back" button links to home page==
```

Here is the code snippet on CodeSandbox, I hope it could illustrate my problem better.

[CodeSandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/l7x8226v99)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this [CodeSandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/j7r872o62y).

I created a new Route for the `/` route. I'm rendering the `<Navigations />` component only in this route.

Is this the effect that you were going for?

Comment: Yes, very cool, thanks! Is this a common pattern with React Router?

Comment: You want to use this pattern because you want your `<Navigations />` component to only show on a particular route.

You should put all of your route-specific components into its own Route.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way you can do this; You need to define the Link component inside the home route.

```js
function App() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <Switch>
                // The link will only be visible on the home route. `/`
                <Route exact path="/">
                    <Link to="/linkAddress">LINK TEXT</Link>
                </Route>
                <Route path="/linkAddress">
                    <Component />
                </Route>
            </Switch>
        </div>
    );
}
```